# iOS Custom TabBar height

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

What is the simplest way to set the `TabBar` height?

I though about adding just a toolbar with buttons, but how do I then navigate between the `ViewControllers` if not modally? I want to replicate the exact `TabBarController` behaviour but with a custom height and buttons.

Thanks!

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044218/change-uitabbar-height#answer-26255545

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change the size of a tabBar. You will have to roll your own. Have a look at container UIViewControllers http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81

Essentially you will create your own TabBarController that will have your own tabBar on the bottom and you will have children viewControllers that you will show when the buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The default `height` of the TabBar is constant and defined by Apple so you can't change it. You should create instead a custom container controller. Have a look to this [custom controller](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mhtabbarcontroller) on [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/), their custom controller is easy to understand. Have a look to the official documentation too on how to create a [custom view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Comment: What is this constant height? How can we get it at runtime? Or at least in apple's doc?