# Change UITabBar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, height, uitabbar

I use `UITabBarController` as a root view and app supports iOS 6 and above. Project class hierarchy is as below.

```
UITabBarController
  - tab1
    - UINavigationController
      - UIViewController
      - UIViewController
      .
      .
  - tab2
    - UINavigationController
      - UIViewController
      - UIViewController
      .
      .
      .
  - tab3
    - UIViewController
  - tab4
    - UIViewController
```

I used below code to change height of `UITabBar` in one of the UIViewControllers (which is inside `UINavigationController`) in above hierarchy.

```
CGRect tabbarFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
tabbarFrame.size.height += 60;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = tabbarFrame;
```

But its not changing the height. `UITabBar` is displayed with default height. Though logging its value prints changed value as shown below.

```
<UITabBar: 0xb528f60; frame = (0 431; 320 109); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb529080>>
```

How can I change `UITabBar`'s height to achieve something like this:?

[image]

Comment: You can change default tabbar height but you need to subclass UITabBarController, i've done it before, i wrote it down on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740824/tab-bar-with-large-icons/16742065#16742065

Comment: Found this was working -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/27494228/1484378

Comment: I think you can also just set a height constraint, it seemed to work to me.

Answer (score 143):

I faced this issue and I was able to solve it.

You have to add following code to your subclass of `UITabBarController` class.

```
const CGFloat kBarHeight = 80;

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame; //self.TabBar is IBOutlet of your TabBar
    tabFrame.size.height = kBarHeight;
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - kBarHeight;
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
}
```

Swift:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    tabBar.frame.size.height = kBarHeight
    tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height - kBarHeight
}
```

Comment: can you specify a bit more? i've added this code to my class that extends TabBarController and nothing happened

Comment: I discarded changing tabBar height because it is a constant defined by Apple, but still couldn't do it (in case I'd be finally interested in resizing it).

Comment: Your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` implementation should call super, probably as the first line.

Comment: @Dklionsk It could call `super`, but it doesn't have to: `The default implementation of this method does nothing.` (from the docs)

Comment: @dmirkitanov that's true for a `UIViewController` but may not be true for `UITabBarController`

Comment: Swift 3.0 version. import Foundation
import UIKit


class NavigationTabBarController: UITabBarController{
    let kBarHeight =  CGFloat(80)

    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame //self.TabBar is IBOutlet of your TabBar
        tabFrame.size.height = kBarHeight
        tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - kBarHeight
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    }
}

Comment: doesn't work well with scrollviews which dont adjust accordingly

Comment: @dmirkitanov, the default implementation of `UIViewController` does nothing, but it's  a `UITabBarController` subclass!

Comment: Changing `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` works in iOS 13.

Comment: doesn't really work for iphonex because of the bottom line thing.

Answer (score 45):

Tested in **XCode 9.0** and **Swift 4**

As suggested in previous answers - inherit `UITabBar` and override `sizeThatFits`, but mark `height` as `@IBInspectable`, so it could be set in the **Interface Builder**:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBar : UITabBar {
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        if height > 0.0 {
            sizeThatFits.height = height
        }
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Set `CustomTabBar` class for the `UITabBar` in the **Identity Inspector** (⌥⌘3):

[image: Tab Bar Identity Inspector]

Then set desired `Height` (greater than `0.0`) in the **Attributes Inspector** (⌥⌘4):

[image: Tab Bar Attributes Inspector]

Comment: Have you thought about making an **extension** instead of Custom Class. And then specifying  `@IBInspectable var height` in the extension. If that is possible, the second step of specifying the Custom Class can be avoided.

Comment: Doesn't works well on iPhone X. You have to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346008/1702909

Answer (score 42):

**Swift3.0, Swift 4.0 compatible**

**Pre-iPhone X** default tab bar height: **49pt**

**iPhone X** default tab bar height: **83pt**

A universal solution supporting every iOS device including **iPhone X** screen size would look like this:

1. Capture UITabBar's default height:

   ```
   fileprivate lazy var defaultTabBarHeight = { tabBar.frame.size.height }()
   ```
2. Adjust UITabBar's height:

   ```
       override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
           super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

           let newTabBarHeight = defaultTabBarHeight + 16.0

           var newFrame = tabBar.frame
           newFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
           newFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight

           tabBar.frame = newFrame
       }
   ```

Comment: This will make the tabBar jump when animating a view change (like a status bar hiding)

Comment: @jakedunc I think it's the issue that S. Azzopardi said, I put this code in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and it works fine.

Comment: @ioio007 Hi this works fine for iPhone x and other devices. But when i increase the height UIView bottom is hiding according the increase value. Help me to get the solution.

Comment: Hi @Saravanan, looks like your problem is the same with the comment below this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293634/7144402

Comment: Change viewWillLayoutSubviews to viewDidLayoutSubviews in UITabBarViewController Class It will work fine. 

it is worked for me.

Answer (score 41):

For *iOS 8.2*, *Xcode 6.2* Swift language:

Create a "DNMainTabVC.swift" (DeveloperNameMainTabViewController.swift file) for your `UITabBarController` (of type `UITabBarController`) and connect it to your storyboard VC.

Add the following lines:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
    // - 40 is editable , the default value is 49 px, below lowers the tabbar and above increases the tab bar size
    tabFrame.size.height = 40
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 40
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: @MS_iOSDeveloper: What do you mean "connect it to storyboard VC"? How to connect it? Thanks!

Comment: You go to your storyboard. Click the viewcontroller, and go to the right side of Xcode to the "view inspector". Under the third tab (which looks like a newspaper) you will find a "Class" Label. The placeholder grey text should say "UIViewController". There you type the name of your viewcontroller file ,ex. "DNMainTabVC". After that a arrow will appear in the Box beside "DNMainTabVC". This means that the viewcontroller file (.swift) is connected to the storyboard element. What ever you write in "DNMainTabVC.swift" will have effect on the storyboard VC.

Comment: @MS_iOSDeveloper got it. so it's selecting custom class. I thought you meant some "dragging" action to "connect". I got it work. thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 30):

Create a custom subclass of type `UITabBar`, then implement the following method :

```
@implementation CustomTabBar
#define kTabBarHeight = // Input the height we want to set for Tabbar here
-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize sizeThatFits = [super sizeThatFits:size];
    sizeThatFits.height = kTabBarHeight;

    return sizeThatFits;
}
@end
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Great! This so far is the best solution I've seen. As it doesn't modify directly the frame but instead changes the expected size! Great!

Comment: This answer does not have side effects in terms of auto layout of the inner view controllers, and it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How can we use this when we make tab bar controller programmatically?

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UITabBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        sizeThatFits.height = 60 // adjust your size here
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
var tabBar:UITabBar?

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var tabFrame: CGRect = self.tabBar!.frame
    tabFrame.size.height = 60
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 60
    self.tabBar!.frame = tabFrame
}
```

Comment: Not working anymore in Swift 2.2. It leaves a clear space below the original tab bar frame

Comment: @jaytrixz Had the same issue. The blank space will appear if you put Alvin's code in viewDidLoad(), but not if you put it in viewWillLayoutSubviews() as suggested

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3.0+** Replace 200 to your desired height in below code.

```
   extension UITabBar {
        override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful! The behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime - original from UITabbar class or your extension

Comment: Works like charm

Comment: You should **NOT** be overriding methods using Swift extensions (or Objective-C categories, for that matter). If you want to use the `sizeThatFits()` approach, use this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425620/538491

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4 & compatible with iphone x**

```
class CustomTabBar : UITabBar {

@IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 65.0

override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else {
      return super.sizeThatFits(size)
    }
    var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    if height > 0.0 {
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            sizeThatFits.height = height + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            sizeThatFits.height = height
        }
    }
    return sizeThatFits
}
}
```

Comment: I used this method definition inside an `extension`, because I'm creating all the UI elements programmatically and, when I tried to set the `tabBar` of my `tabBarController` by overriding the `tabBar` attribute, it displays an empty tabBar (without items)

Comment: guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow is deprecated in iOS 13.0. So please update.

Answer (score 7):

Building up on previous answers and updating for Swift 3.

Subclass UITabController and make sure to assign your new custom class to the Identity Inspector of your UITabController.

**Swift 3.0**

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        var newTabBarFrame = tabBar.frame

        let newTabBarHeight: CGFloat = 60
        newTabBarFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
        newTabBarFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight

        tabBar.frame = newTabBarFrame
    }
}
```

***Warning***: if you get a blank space below your tab bar, make sure you did put this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews() and not viewDidLoad().

Comment: This works, however some of the view got blocked by tab bar because of the increased height.. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hey @john. Are you pinning them to the safe area bottom margin?

Comment: Hi @Kqtr, I pinned the view to the bottom view like:

`NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutAttribute.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)`

I found `safeAreaInsets` and `safeAreaLayoutGuide` but the feature only available for iOS 11 and above. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, you could try, on iOS 11 and above, to use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, where view is the VC's main view. And below iOS 11, pin to VC's bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor. Currently, you are using the view's bottom, and the view might go lower than those bottom guides.

Comment: @john also, FYI, for convenience I created 4 variables in an VC extension that provides simple constraints to use (repeat for left right & top): extension UIViewController { var safeBottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            return view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
        } else {
            return bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor
        }
    }
}

Comment: good one, I have done that but did it as a `UIView` extension, like: `extension UIView { var safeTopAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor } else { return self.topAnchor }  }` Thank for sharing BTW 

Comment: My pleasure! And careful because below iOS 11, I suspect that your extension will pin to the top of the view which, in the case of a VC's main view, will be the top of the status bar, whereas it will be the bottom of the status bar using the VC's topLayoutGuide.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, the answer from @Rushikesh was working pretty well until **iOS 10** but I had some issues with **iOS 11** and **Swift 3.2**.

The tabBar was changing its frame every time I touched a new tab.

I fixed this by putting the code in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function instead of `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

**Swift 3 :**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var tabFrame            = tabBar.frame
    tabFrame.size.height    = 65
    tabFrame.origin.y       = view.frame.size.height - 65
    tabBar.frame            = tabFrame
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Xamarin implementation:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
    const float newTabBarHeight = 40f;
    TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y + (TabBar.Frame.Height - newTabBarHeight), TabBar.Frame.Width, newTabBarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Edited Kiarash Asar's answers with use of Safe Area:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    var safeAreaBottomInset: CGFloat = 0.0

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        safeAreaBottomInset = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }

    let newTabBarHeight: CGFloat = {{myDesiredHeight}} + safeAreaBottomInset

    var newFrame = tabBar.frame
    newFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
    newFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight

    tabBar.frame = newFrame
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the tab bar's height by subclassing it. I actually did this long time ago. xcode 6.0

```
override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: super.sizeThatFits(size).width, height: 60)
}
```

That should return its default width with the height of 60pts.

Answer (score 4):

this is also one way to do that

```
extension UITabBar {

override public func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    super.sizeThatFits(size)
    var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    sizeThatFits.height = 71 // or whatever height you need
    return sizeThatFits
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5.3.1, XCode 11+, iOS 14:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    let height: CGFloat = 62
    
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                .compactMap({$0})
                .first?.windows
                .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first else {
            return super.sizeThatFits(size)
        }

        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            sizeThatFits.height = height + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            sizeThatFits.height = height
        }
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add more inset to the bottom of the safe area:

```
additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom = 40
```

[image]

Comment: This combined with moving the tab bar item title and image down, to have them centered is probably the neatest solution. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

WORKS WITH ALL SCREEN SIZES:
Set the tabBarHeight to the (original height of the tabBar - 20) this is important so you can use it later in the viewDidLayoutSubviews, also better than hard coding the size you want. Since that size might not work on all screens.

Window safe area insets keeps the necessary padding at the bottom of the tab bar height in order to maintain the distance from the bottom edge of the screen.

```
var tabBarHeight = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBarHeight = self.tabBar.frame.height - 20
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {return}
        tabFrame.size.height = tabBarHeight + window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    //MARK:- Variable
    let HEIGHT_TAB_BAR:CGFloat = 500

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
        tabFrame.size.height = HEIGHT_TAB_BAR
        tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - HEIGHT_TAB_BAR
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    }


}
```

Worked fine for me.

Comment: causes endless loop for me. I think viewDidLayoutSubviews is getting called again because tabBar's frame is modified

Answer (score 1):

iPhoneX have have different height so if we move to smaller height then tabbar shape will be bad in iPhoneX

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    int requiredHeight = 55;
    CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
    if (tabFrame.size.height < requiredHeight)
    {
        tabFrame.size.height = requiredHeight;
        tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - requiredHeight;
        self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For a UITabBarController subclass**

Create a subclass from UITabBar

```
class CustomTabBar : UITabBar {
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        super.sizeThatFits(size)
        var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        sizeThatFits.height = 200
        return sizeThatFits
    }
}
```

and set the class in the constructor

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    object_setClass(self.tabBar, CustomTabBar.self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        tabBar.frame.size.height = 60
        tabBar.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height - 60
}
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26255545/2227743) (and other ones). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI, I use Introspect [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

Then in your TabView view modifier, increase the size of your view by adding to the height.  Here I am adding 7 pts then another 2.5 pts for a custom divider line.  And I added it differently for iPhone vs. iPad.

```
.introspectTabBarController { UITabBarController in
    if sizeClass == .compact {
      let barIncrease = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -7, width: UITabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 9))
      barIncrease.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#508FD6FF")
      UITabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(barIncrease)
      let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -9.5, width: UITabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 2.5))
      lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#508FD6FF")
      UITabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
    } else {
      let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -2.5, width: UITabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 2.5))
      lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#508FD6FF")
      UITabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a solution with `CustomTabBar`, but I ended up getting a lot of exceptions which didn't tell me anything. Every time I was getting a different error, or sometimes no error at all. For example one of the errors in a random place:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
```

Or:

```
malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x14ce4c790: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0xb000000000000001
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I searched for a solution and on Apple's dev-forum user **eskimo** advised to use [Standard Memory Debugging Tools](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92102).

**Zombies** instrument didn't help, but [Address Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early) helped to identify the problem at once!

**Error log:**

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow MyTabBarController.swift in MyTabBarController.CustomTabBar.hasBanner.setter

thread #1: tid = 0x6801d, 0x00000001089bb250 libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie(), queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Heap buffer overflow

{
  "access_size": 1,
  "access_type": 1,
  "address": 4918104816,
  "description": "heap-buffer-overflow",
  "instrumentation_class": "AddressSanitizer",
  "pc": 4382625148,
  "stop_type":
```

The problem was that I used an instance variable in CustomTabBar. For some reason it was causing crashes. I've switched the var to a static and it solved the problem!

**Here is the working code:**

```swift
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // We have to put all init logic here because:
        // `UITabBarController` calls `loadView()` inside `super.init()` method,
        // which causes the call to `viewDidLoad()`.
        // So the `viewDidLoad()` method will be called before `init()` has finished its job.

        object_setClass(tabBar, CustomTabBar.self)
        
        CustomTabBar.hasBanner = InAppPurchaseManager.shared.activeSubscription == nil
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
    
}

extension MyTabBarController {
    
    class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
        
        // We have to use a static var `hasBanner`
        // because an instance var causes a Heap Buffer Overflow.
        static var hasBanner: Bool = true // <------------------- THE SOLUTION
        
        override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            var sizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
            sizeThatFits.height = Constants.Layout.tabBarHeight + (Self.hasBanner ? 44 : 0)
            return sizeThatFits
        }
        
    }
    
}
```