# How to reduce the height of UITabbar in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How I can reduce the height of UITabBar in xamarin ios. I want to reduce the height of UITabbar for some pixels. But not getting any way to fix it.
How I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change UITabBar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044218/change-uitabbar-height)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405017/3151675).