# UITabBar items jumping on back navigation on iOS 12.1

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have an iOS app with `UITabBarController` on a master screen, navigating to a detail screen hiding the `UITabBarController` with setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`.

When going back to the master screen the `UITabBarController` does a strange "jump" as shown on this GIF:

[image]

This happens **only on iOS 12.1**, not on 12.0 or 11.x.

Seems like an iOS 12.1 bug, because I noticed other apps like FB Messenger with this behavior, but I was wondering, is there some kind of workaround for it?

Comment: I was wondering why this wasn't posted yet(or maybe i missed it!). It's even there on whatsApp.

Comment: This has been solved in the new iOS 12.1.1 (currently released as a beta version)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your `UITabBarController`, set `isTranslucent = false`

Comment: In UITabBarController, `[self.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];` It's work! Thanks.

Comment: And if you want to keep the tab bar translucent? This is hardly a fix for the problem.

Comment: This works, but if you want to keep the tab translucent try my solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170130/5766867

Comment: Why is this happening, and why does setting the tab bar to translucent fix it?

Comment: Now I have problems with tableView bottom inset :(

Answer (score 9):

Apple has now fixed that in **iOS 12.1.1**

Comment: is it only a bug from iOS 12 or it was existing before also? i experienced it in 12.1.0 and then updated my iPhone to 12.1.2 so bug is disappeared now. but i want to know should i restrict it from all previous iOS versions or only for 12.1.0's. thanx!

Comment: @SerjRubens the bug was introduced in iOS 12 and fixed in iOS 12.1.1. I don't understand what do you mean by restricting the bug from the previous iOS versions

Comment: ah ok, thats what i wanna know, thanks :) p.s. restricting mb not a best word but i added condition like below to avoid this bug from previous versions: tabBar.isTranslucent = ProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeast(OperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 12, minorVersion: 1, patchVersion: 1)). so now i can change it as far as you saying it was ok in versions before 12 :)

Comment: Actually, I'm using Xcode 10.1 with a iOS target of 10.0, and I'm seeing the exact same bug behavior of a tab bar jump.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it's Apple's bug
But you can try this as a hot fix: just create a class for your tabBar with following code:

```
import UIKit

class FixedTabBar: UITabBar {

    var itemFrames = [CGRect]()
    var tabBarItems = [UIView]()


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if itemFrames.isEmpty, let UITabBarButtonClass = NSClassFromString("UITabBarButton") as? NSObject.Type {
            tabBarItems = subviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UITabBarButtonClass)})
            tabBarItems.forEach({itemFrames.append($0.frame)})
        }

        if !itemFrames.isEmpty, !tabBarItems.isEmpty, itemFrames.count == items?.count {
            tabBarItems.enumerated().forEach({$0.element.frame = itemFrames[$0.offset]})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, I want to try it out but using a custom `UITabBar` with a `UITabBarController` turns out to be not that easy ...

Comment: Trying it out now, seems promising, it just does not handle orientation change

Comment: @IgorKulman I didn't test it with different orientations... I will try to investigate on weekend

Answer (score 4):

In my case (iOS 12.1.4), I found that this weird glitchy behaviour was triggered by modals being presented with the `.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

After updating their presentationStyle to **`.overFullScreen`**, the glitch went away.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that can handle rotation and tab bar items being added or removed:

```
class FixedTabBar: UITabBar {

    var buttonFrames: [CGRect] = []
    var size: CGSize = .zero

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if UIDevice.current.systemVersion >= "12.1" {
            let buttons = subviews.filter {
                String(describing: type(of: $0)).hasSuffix("Button")
            }
            if buttonFrames.count == buttons.count, size == bounds.size {
                zip(buttons, buttonFrames).forEach { $0.0.frame = $0.1 }
            } else {
                buttonFrames = buttons.map { $0.frame }
                size = bounds.size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

extension UITabBar{

open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let UITabBarButtonClass = NSClassFromString("UITabBarButton") as? NSObject.Type{
        let subItems = self.subviews.filter({return $0.isKind(of: UITabBarButtonClass)})
        if subItems.count > 0{
            let tmpWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(subItems.count)
            for (index,item) in subItems.enumerated(){
                item.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(index) * tmpWidth, y: 0, width: tmpWidth, height: item.bounds.height)
                }
            }
        }
    }

open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let view:UITabBar = super.hitTest(point, with: event) as? UITabBar{
        for item in view.subviews{
            if point.x >= item.frame.origin.x  && point.x <= item.frame.origin.x + item.frame.size.width{
                return item
                }
            }
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: @user10589608 I take it back, works on 6S but not on XS Max, on XS Max the UI looks really off

Comment: Also looks off when rotating the device to landscape

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to fix this issue,
Firstly, In your UITabBarController, set isTranslucent = false like:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

sencondly, if the first solution does not fix your issur, try this way:

here is the Objective-C code

```
// .h
@interface CYLTabBar : UITabBar
@end 

// .m
#import "CYLTabBar.h"

CG_INLINE BOOL
OverrideImplementation(Class targetClass, SEL targetSelector, id (^implementationBlock)(Class originClass, SEL originCMD, IMP originIMP)) {
   Method originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, targetSelector);
   if (!originMethod) {
       return NO;
   }
   IMP originIMP = method_getImplementation(originMethod);
   method_setImplementation(originMethod, imp_implementationWithBlock(implementationBlock(targetClass, targetSelector, originIMP)));
   return YES;
}
@implementation CYLTabBar

+ (void)load {

   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       if (@available(iOS 12.1, *)) {
           OverrideImplementation(NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton"), @selector(setFrame:), ^id(__unsafe_unretained Class originClass, SEL originCMD, IMP originIMP) {
               return ^(UIView *selfObject, CGRect firstArgv) {

                   if ([selfObject isKindOfClass:originClass]) {

                       if (!CGRectIsEmpty(selfObject.frame) && CGRectIsEmpty(firstArgv)) {
                           return;
                       }
                   }

                   // call super
                   void (*originSelectorIMP)(id, SEL, CGRect);
                   originSelectorIMP = (void (*)(id, SEL, CGRect))originIMP;
                   originSelectorIMP(selfObject, originCMD, firstArgv);
               };
           });
       }
   });
}
@end
```

More information:https://github.com/ChenYilong/CYLTabBarController/commit/2c741c8bffd47763ad2fca198202946a2a63c4fc

Comment: You should mention that your code is quoted from『github.com/QMUI/QMUI_iOS/issues/410』

Answer (score 1):

You can override `- (UIEdgeInsets)safeAreaInsets` method for few iOS 12 subversions with this:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)safeAreaInsets {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = [super safeAreaInsets];
    CGFloat h = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
    if (insets.bottom >= h) {
        insets.bottom = [self.window safeAreaInsets].bottom;
    }
    return insets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea of [@ElonChan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111977/2007403), 
I just changed the c inline function to OC static method, since I won't use this `overrideImplementation` too much. And also, this snippet was adjusted to iPhoneX now.

```
static CGFloat const kIPhoneXTabbarButtonErrorHeight = 33;
static CGFloat const kIPhoneXTabbarButtonHeight = 48;


@implementation FixedTabBar


typedef void(^NewTabBarButtonFrameSetter)(UIView *, CGRect);
typedef NewTabBarButtonFrameSetter (^ImpBlock)(Class originClass, SEL originCMD, IMP originIMP);


+ (BOOL)overrideImplementationWithTargetClass:(Class)targetClass targetSelector:(SEL)targetSelector implementBlock:(ImpBlock)implementationBlock {
    Method originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(targetClass, targetSelector);
    if (!originMethod) {
        return NO;
    }
    IMP originIMP = method_getImplementation(originMethod);
    method_setImplementation(originMethod, imp_implementationWithBlock(implementationBlock(targetClass, targetSelector, originIMP)));
    return YES;
}


+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (@available(iOS 12.1, *)) {
            [self overrideImplementationWithTargetClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton")
                                         targetSelector:@selector(setFrame:)
                                         implementBlock:^NewTabBarButtonFrameSetter(__unsafe_unretained Class originClass, SEL originCMD, IMP originIMP) {
                return ^(UIView *selfObject, CGRect firstArgv) {
                    if ([selfObject isKindOfClass:originClass]) {
                        if (!CGRectIsEmpty(selfObject.frame) && CGRectIsEmpty(firstArgv)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (firstArgv.size.height == kIPhoneXTabbarButtonErrorHeight) {
                            firstArgv.size.height = kIPhoneXTabbarButtonHeight;
                        }
                    }
                    void (*originSelectorIMP)(id, SEL, CGRect);
                    originSelectorIMP = (void (*)(id, SEL, CGRect))originIMP;
                    originSelectorIMP(selfObject, originCMD, firstArgv);
                };
            }];
        }
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the swift code

```
extension UIApplication {
open override var next: UIResponder? {
    // Called before applicationDidFinishLaunching
    SwizzlingHelper.enableInjection()
    return super.next
}
```

}

class SwizzlingHelper {

```
static func enableInjection() {
    DispatchQueue.once(token: "com.SwizzlingInjection") {
        //what to need inject
        UITabbarButtonInjection.inject()
    }
```

}
more information https://github.com/tonySwiftDev/UITabbar-fixIOS12.1Bug

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue, where the app was architectured with one navigation controller per tab. The easiest non-hacky way that I found to fix this, was to place the `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`, and remove the individual `UINavigationController`s.

**Before:**

```
                   -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
                   -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
                   -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
                   -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController
```

**After:**

```
                                             -> UIViewController
                                             -> UIViewController
UINavigationController -> UITabBarController -> UIViewController
                                             -> UIViewController
                                             -> UIViewController
```

By using the outer `UINavigationController`, you don't need to hide the `UITabBar` when pushing a view controller onto the navigation stack.

**Caveat:**

The only issue I found so far, is that setting the title or right/left bar button items on each `UIViewController` does not have the same effect. To overcome this issue, I applied the changes via the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` when the visible `UIViewController` has changed.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    guard let topItem = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem else { return }
    precondition(self.navigationController == viewController.navigationController, "Navigation controllers do not match. The following changes might result in unexpected behaviour.")
    topItem.title = viewController.title
    topItem.titleView = viewController.navigationItem.titleView
    topItem.leftBarButtonItem = viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
    topItem.rightBarButtonItem = viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
}
```

Note that I have added a `preconditionFailure` to catch any case when the navigation architecture has been modified

Answer (score -1):

If you still want to keep your tab bar translucent you need to subclass from `UITabBar` and override property `safeAreaInsets`

```
class MyTabBar: UITabBar {

private var safeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    set {
        if newValue != UIEdgeInsets.zero {
            safeInsets = newValue
        }
    }
    get {
        return safeInsets
    }
}
```

}

The idea is to not allow system to set `zero` insets, so tab bar won't jump.