# The height of tab bar will changes when pop a UIWebViewController and then back to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

I notice that the height of `UITabBarController` tab bar will be compressed when pop a `UIViewController` contains a web view and then back to `UITabBarController` in iOS 12 devices. Like this:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: @Mateusz. Thanks for your edit.

Comment: The right solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084806/uitabbar-items-jumping-on-back-navigation-on-ios-12-1

Answer (score 2):

**Use this**

```
import UIKit

class FixedTabBar: UITabBar {

    var itemFrames = [CGRect]()
    var tabBarItems = [UIView]()


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if itemFrames.isEmpty, let UITabBarButtonClass = NSClassFromString("UITabBarButton") as? NSObject.Type {
            tabBarItems = subviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UITabBarButtonClass)})
            tabBarItems.forEach({itemFrames.append($0.frame)})
        }

        if !itemFrames.isEmpty, !tabBarItems.isEmpty, itemFrames.count == items?.count {
            tabBarItems.enumerated().forEach({$0.element.frame = itemFrames[$0.offset]})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZeroOnet You're welcome)) Please rate my answer if it helped you.