# Incorrect display of items on UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk

If the property is enabled:

```
 self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

then when you swipe back items on TabBar are displayed incorrectly.

This bug can be found in WhatsApp

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: how I can fix this?

Comment: If it’s in other apps, it’s probably an iOS bug. File a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @matt, if it is in other app, it might as well be that app's bug =))

Comment: Is it happening on iOS12.1 only?

Comment: yes, iOS 12.1 only

Comment: @КузинДмитрий I have seen it before, look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084806/uitabbar-items-jumping-on-back-navigation-on-ios-12-1

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084806/uitabbar-items-jumping-on-back-navigation-on-ios-12-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITabBar items jumping on back navigation on iOS 12.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084806/uitabbar-items-jumping-on-back-navigation-on-ios-12-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UITabBarController`, set 
`isTranslucent = false`

thanks [Vanya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385469/vanya)