# Subclass UITabBar without Storyboard to increase height

Tags: ios, objective-c

To my understanding, the only way to subclass UITabBar (to increase the height) in a UITabBarController is to implement a storyboard and assign the subclass directly via the interface builder.

I was wondering if it would be possible to simply swizzle self.tabBar to our own subclassed tab bar, but that probably wouldn’t work.

Any other ideas? I’m simply trying to increase the height of the tab bar, while not breaking or conflicting with the superview’s constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through all the answers given in the following link.

[Change UITabBar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044218/change-uitabbar-height)

In this example people have given ways to customize height without even subclassing.

Comment: Already saw that thread. I’m wondering if swizzling will help with drawing the initial UITabBar, or any other solutions that aren’t setting the view controller height.

Comment: First of all you are not setting the height of the view controller, whereas you are setting the height of the tab bar. Other than that, swizzling is not a very good pattern to use.. This is used as a last resort of all the available solution.